# Spring Boot Integration Tests, @Autowired works, @Inject does not, Why?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired, inject

I work on a Spring Boot application, I have written a Service and I want to test this Service in an Integration Test. Therefor I want to Inject the Service Into my test. If I use the @Inject annotation, The Service is null. If I use @Autowired, the Service gets Injected and the test works. I thought the annotation should do more or less the same, with the only differrence that @Autowired fails if no bean is available, because it is default set to required=true.The Service has an Interface and I choose the implementation based on Field Name.

Interface:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface FileService {

     boolean storeDicomZip(InputStream stream, long caseId);

  .
  . 
  .
  }
```

Implementation:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class FileSystemFileService implements FileService {

 .
 .
 .
 }
```

And The Test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class FileSystemFileServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    private FileService fileSystemFileService;


    @Test
    public void storeDicomZip() throws Exception {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("TEST".getBytes());
        fileSystemFileService.storeDicomZip(stream, 3);
        Assert.assertTrue(fileSystemFileService.getDicomZipVersions(3) == 1);
    }

    .
    . 
    .


}
```

As described, If I use @Autowired, like here it works, if I use @Inject it does not because fileSystemFileService is null.

Does somebody know why this is the case, and what I have to change to use @Inject?

Comment: No answer so far?

Comment: @Dedyshka Nope.